# com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'

Tags: ssl, encryption, ibm-mq

We recently upgraded the IBM MQ client in our application from version 7.5.0.5 to 9.3, and we also transitioned from Java 1.8 to Java 11. However, after the upgrade, we encountered the following error while attempting to establish an SSL connection with the queue manager using the cipher 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA'. Interestingly, this same connection functions properly with version 7.5.0.5 and Java 1.8.

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.constructMQCD(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:1303)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.constructCNO(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:1396)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:233)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:449)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:486)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:97)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:194)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:870)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:818)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:760)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:200)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:1004)
    at com.test.sample.transport.mq.MqTransportActor.startSenderTransport(MqTransportActor.java:148)
    at com.test.sample.transport.mq.MqTransportActor.onReceive(MqTransportActor.java:75)
    at akka.actor.UntypedAbstractActor$$anon$1.applyOrElse(AbstractActor.scala:332)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:471)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

Given that the Queue Manager is maintained by the customer, we currently lack it's version information.

As the trial version of IBM MQ Explorer 7.5.0.5 is not accessible, we conducted tests using version 9.2 of IBM MQ Explorer. During testing, we observed that our upgraded code (using client version 9.3 and Java 11) successfully establishes an SSL connection. However, this successful connection occurred with the cipher suite "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256."

We encountered difficulty in configuring the setup using "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" due to its deprecation in the latest version of IBM MQ Explorer. Unfortunately, IBM MQ Explorer 7.5.0.5 is not accessible.

If you have any further insights or recommendations regarding this situation, we would greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: You would need to enable deprecated ciphersuites since that is TLS1.0.  I would suggest you contact your customer to see if they will let you switch to a TLS1.2 cipher, most companies I deal with want to get to 1.2 since 1.0 is no longer considered secure.